# Vlookup using variable references

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I was hoping to define some variables and put them within a vlookup formula.  I have outlined below a simple example of what I'm trying to achieve.  However I keep getting a '438' error message.

I have put in the original vlookup without the variables and the vlookup with the variables in that are not working.  Any input would be appreciated.  I believe I have variables defined correctly but I think it's something to do with the way I'm calling them in the formula.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim Lookupcolumn As Range

Dim columnletter_start As String

Dim columnletter_End As String

columnletter_start = ActiveCell.offfet(0, 1).Value

columnletter_End = ActiveCell.offfet(0, 2).Value

Set Lookupcolumn = Sheets("Pricing Analysis").Cells.Find(What:="Cusip", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

'ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R[1]C[-8],'CS Primeview'!C[-6]:C[-4],3,FALSE)"

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(Lookupcolumn,'CS Primeview'columnletter_start:columnletter_End,3,FALSE)"


End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to do it like this `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(Lookupcolumn,'CS Primeview'" & columnletter_start & ":" & columnletter_End & ",3,FALSE)"` - otherwise, the formula uses the names of the variables rather than their contents.

Comment: Thank you Matt for your advise.  For the 'Lookupcolumn' which I have set as a range - it is just reading it as actual "lookupcolumn" and not the range - do you know what I do to correct this?  Thanks again.

Comment: Ah I missed that - same issue again... you need to remove that from the double quotes. Like this: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(" & Lookupcolumn & ",'CS Primeview'" & columnletter_start & ":" & columnletter_End & ",3,FALSE)"`. You may also need to use LookupColumn.Address if it doesn't work with the range reference on its own.

Comment: Thanks again for your help - it was extremely useful.  Plus thanks for taking the time out.  Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that indeed you may use any Excel function in your VBA code via `Excel.WorksheetFunction.` structure and obtain correct results using variables.
However, for your code `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(Lookupcolumn,'CS Primeview'columnletter_start:columnletter_End,3,FALSE)"` you try to use **Range** object as reference in `VLOOKUP`, but Excel understands as the argument only valid reference as `A1` or Named Region.

As a solution try to generate `A1`-similar argument in your code. For the entire column `A:A` will go. Good luck!

P.S. One more thing I noticed: `'CS Primeview'columnletter_start:columnletter_End` - for this part it seems you missed exclamation before reference, as well as double quotes to concatenate parts, i.e. `"'CS Primeview'!" & columnletter_start & ":" & columnletter_End` should be correct.

Comment: Peter - Thank you for your input and time spent typing up the answer.  I got to understand a lot from it.  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks a mill to Peter and Matt.

Comment: @user1624926 you're welcome! The question was great as well! (:

Answer (score 0):

The below allows you to define a variable cell reference and then convert it into a format that is readable in the .formula way. This is an easy method to have a vlookup with a variable, as you can write formulas up in excel and then copy/paste them into code and just change the lookup value. This will work for index/match perfectly fine, too.

```
lookup_value = Cells(defined_row,defined_column).Address(False,False)
lookup_value = Replace(lookup_value, "", "")

ActiveCell.Formula = "VLOOKUP($" & lookup_value & ",'Sheet1'!$A:$B,2,0)"
```